# Converter visible when empty

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

How can I make a converter VisibleWhenEmptyString. I did it as below but it does not work. Regards

```
    <converters:ValueWhenConverter x:Key="VisibleWhenEmptyString">
    <converters:ValueWhenConverter.When>
        <x:String ></x:String>
    </converters:ValueWhenConverter.When>
    <converters:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
    </converters:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
    <converters:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
    </converters:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
</converters:ValueWhenConverter>
```

Comment: Have you solved your issue by my reply?

Answer (score 0):

If you directly use Template10 source code to debug the [ValueWhenConverter](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/c2c35b131fac81f7396d141d6212c96ff9146225/Source/Template10.Extras.10586/Xaml.Converters/ValueWhenConverter.cs#L19), you would see that it actually is a null value when you set `<x:String ></x:String>`.

[image]

So, when your Binding path value is `string.Empty`, you could directly change it to `null`. It's the simplest way to solve this issue.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:ValueWhenConverter x:Key="VisibleWhenTrueConverter">
        <converters:ValueWhenConverter.When>
            <x:String></x:String>
        </converters:ValueWhenConverter.When>
        <converters:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
        </converters:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
        <converters:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
        </converters:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
    </converters:ValueWhenConverter>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello Admin" Visibility="{x:Bind IsAdmin, Converter={StaticResource VisibleWhenTrueConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private string _IsAdmin;
    public string IsAdmin
    {
        get { return _IsAdmin; }
        set
        {
            if (value == string.Empty)
            {
                _IsAdmin = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _IsAdmin = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        IsAdmin = string.Empty; ;
    }
}
```